# How can I make an OSM map without icons and labels?

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript, openstreetmap, web-mapping

I want to create a web application that include Open Street Map .
I use OpenLayers library to create map , but now I want to create map without icons like hospitals,coffeshop and other icons.

This images explain:
[image: Before]

[image: After,without icons and lable]

Comment: Your map is an image. Some servers provide alternative rendering, or you can create your own style.

Answer (score 4):

As BradHards already mentioned you'll need to render your own map tiles.

On help.openstreetmap.org there is a list of many opportunities: https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/136/how-do-i-render-my-own-maps-for-my-website.

A similar post on gis.stackexchange: [How would I draw and visualize custom maps based on OSM data?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/452/how-would-i-draw-and-visualize-custom-maps-based-on-osm-data/487#487)

Comment: ... or at https://help.openstreetmap.org do a search for the keyword "without"